# Getting a TextBox to accept user input, not open a folder browser

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on updating a C# project that makes use of WinForms. One of the minor changes I want to make is as follows.

The project has a Form that currently allows the user to click a Button, which then opens a Folder Browser window where they can select a folder for the project to retrieve information from. The selected directory is entered into a TextBox after being selected. However, clicking on the TextBox also opens up a Folder Browser window. You are also currently unable to manually enter text into the TextBox.

What I want to do is (hopefully) pretty simple: I want the user to be able to enter a directory manually into the TextBox and for the project to accept that text input, and for the TextBox to not open a Folder Browser form upon being clicked.

Some other things to keep in mind:

1. I am not familiar with all the ins and outs of WinForms, so I could very well be missing something simple that I could do.
2. I am also in the process of completely restructuring the project, so if this is not possible in WinForms, but is possible in, say, WPF, that would not be a major obstacle for me in this case.

Here is the code for the Button, or at least the pertinent part, as a reference. `txtProjectDir` is the TextBox in question. Not much else is done with the TextBox in the code except for this part.

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chooseProjectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        clbConvertProjects.Items.Clear();
        clbProjects.Items.Clear();
        txtProjectDir.Text = chooseProjectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
        cur_projDir = txtProjectDir.Text;
```

**Update**: I have made some changes based on the input of several users (thanks to all of you, by the way). This is what the pertinent part of the code looks like now:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chooseProjectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        clbConvertProjects.Items.Clear();
        clbProjects.Items.Clear();
        cur_projDir = txtProjectDir.Text;
```

I also had to change the TextBox to not be read-only, as well as remove a reference to the above method from its Event properties. Now it is able to accept user input, and doesn't open a Folder Browser when clicked into.

The only problem is this: if I only enter text directly into the TextBox, instead of selecting a folder via the browser popup, the program doesn't seem to properly accept the input (i.e., no information is being collected from the directory). Obviously, I still need to make the program accept user input, as it currently doesn't.

**Update 2**: After more suggestions (again, thanks guys) and good old trial-and-error, I have re-inserted the line `txtProjectDir.Text = chooseProjectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;` as removing it from the method had undesired effects on the program's functionality. I am still having an issue with the program accepting the user's manual input into the TextBox, though.

**Update 3**: As per @blaze_125's recommendation, I am going to have to create a new event for the TextBox when the user Leaves it. Thank you all for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: You are missing something simple.  Select the box in the designer and click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Shows you what events are being used.

Comment: What @Hans means is that the Enter, GotFocus or Click event of the textbox probably also is handled by `btnBrowse_Click`, either directly or indirectly. It sounds like a smart hack to not have to validate the input, but even folders chosen using the folder browser window can be renamed, deleted or otherwise be (made) inaccessible afterwards.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The only event for the TextBox is Action -> Click, which is set to `btnBrowse_Click`. No other events are populated. Clearly that isn't what I want to happen, so I suppose I need to make a new method for it?

Comment: Right-click => Reset.

Comment: `btnBrowse_Click` is not what you want to happen, but that is the event that is linked. so that is the event you want to remove from that textbox. In your current requirements, only the button should be calling `btnBrowse_Click`, but currently you have both your button AND textbox doing it.

Comment: @blaze_125 Right. I have reset `txtProjectDir` to not have `btnBrowse_Click` as its Click event. Now the question is this: what should go where for the TextBox to do what I want it to do?

Comment: @MrM21632, at this point you *should* have nothing else to do. But I have never seen the code base you are working on, so I could be out for lunch on this statement. Theoretically, the code behind is already setup to read whatever is in that textbox. `How the box gets filled` is *usually* irrelevant. Try it out. Run your app, manually put in a path and see what happens. If it throws up an error. Make a new SO question, with the error and behavior, and the community will tackle it.

Comment: Fair enough. I will do a quick build and see if that works. I'll update the OP with the results.

Comment: @MrM21632, I believe you will need to remove this line `txtProjectDir.Text = chooseProjectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;` from `btnBrowse_Click`

Comment: @Tom: I shall do this as well.

Comment: @Tom. No. If he does, then he'll kill the button's functionality. I mean... the code will compile, the folder browser will come up when the button is clicked, but the textbox will not be updated when the user selects a folder from the folder browser. The `intent` in this post `is to remove` the `button event` `from the textbox`. Not to remove the button and the event altogether.

Comment: @Blaze_125, The Op was to stop the Dialog and to allow manual input? if that line is still there the code will expect the dialog to give the file path?

Comment: @Tom, if the user clicks the button, then a dialog comes up `if (chooseProjectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` aka if the user pressed ok on the dialog, `txtProjectDir.Text = chooseProjectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;` then make the textbox value equal to the selected path. Before this post, that event used to occur on button click AND textbox click. Now that we remove the textbox click, it only happens on button click. The event still need to go on if the button is clicked. User can now enter path manualy by clicking the textbox and typing, or by clicking the button and selecting.

Comment: My *textual mathematics* tell me that `The project has a Form that currently allows the user to click a Button, which then opens a Folder.` + 
`However, clicking on the TextBox also opens up a Folder Browser window. You are also currently unable to manually enter text into the TextBox.` means he wants to _remove_ `Textblox Click event`, but _keep_ `Button and Button Click Event`

Comment: @MrM21632, following the post update you just made... Leave the method `private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` alone. Just remove the action from the textbox as mentioned in my answer and run your program. If it blows up, then let us know. Otherwise, go on with your day.

Comment: @blaze_125: Exactly. I have updated my post with the results of the latest compile. I will need to reverse Tom's suggestion, though.

Comment: if you are still having issues, I'm guessing an error message comes up? What does it say? I have the feeling the answer to your current issue might be in the code we don't see below `cur_projDir = txtProjectDir.Text;`. Before us, the folder path could only ever be entered by the button event, which likely does more than just populate the textbox with the selected path.  Post the whole btn click method if you can.

Comment: @blaze_125: There actually isn't an error message. It just isn't gathering the information it needs to from the directory I enter. My best guess is that it simply isn't setting `cur_projDir` to anything when you only enter the directory manually.

Comment: Good point, that is likely. Look at what's being done with the selected path in that method. the same needs to happen when a path is manually entered. I suggest you add a "Leave" event to your textbox. You took out a `click` event, now you should put in a `Leave` event which will `qualify` or do whatever to your path when the user leaves the textbox. In that `Leave` event, you'll want to do this `cur_projDir = txtProjectDir.Text;` along with everything else you see relevant in the current button click method. To remove the event earlier, you removed the text. To add one, double click the cell.

Comment: @blaze_125: That sounds like the exact course of action I'll need to take. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, clicking on the TextBox also opens up a Folder Browser window.
>
> > The only event for the TextBox is Action -> Click, which is set to btnBrowse_Click
> >
> > > What I want to do is (hopefully) pretty simple: I want the user to be able to enter a directory manually into the TextBox and for the project to accept that text input, and for the TextBox to not open a Folder Browser form upon being clicked.

If you don't want that event(aka `action->click`) to happen, then you must remove the text `btnBrowse_Click` from that textbox and leave it blank. That will remove the `event` you currently have linked to your textbox click.

Comment: To add to this answer, so that it's here as well: once you remove the Click event from the TextBox, you'll need to add a new method for when you Leave the TextBox, so that the same general result will occur if you enter text manually. Thanks again, blaze!

Answer (score 0):

There will be an even linked to the text box `txtProjectDir` to check this select the text box and in the properties select the lightning bolt.

[image]

I would assume that the even is a click into the `textbox` however.

If this is the case you probably want to remove this.

Now in terms of how to accept what is in the text box as the value you just want to reference the text and that is in the `textbox` whitch would be `txtProjectDir.Text`

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chooseProjectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        clbConvertProjects.Items.Clear();
        clbProjects.Items.Clear();
        cur_projDir = txtProjectDir.Text;
```

Comment: Sounds like half an answer. If the event is linked, then what?

Comment: @CodeCaster Then it needs to unlinked - delete the event handler name from the right hand column

Comment: @CodeCaster, if the event is linked in the visual display of the properties, then the user can simply remove the "link" by removing the text in that textbox. Visual Studio then takes care of removing the references in the code behind, though it will likely not remove the method that was attached to the event. So once you remove the link from the visual interface, you end up with a unused method in the code behind. If however the "link" is actually in the code behind rather than through the visual interface, then the user must look for it and remove the event subscription directly from the code

Comment: @blaze yes, I know how the WinForms designers work. The OP doesn't, so the answer should be [edit]ed to include that.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I know... Putting it in comment so that if it does not make it in the answer post, at least it will be here ;) a tad lower...